# What is the method to "clear effects" in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects, shapes

Once I have made a shape and added particular layer effects, these effects automatically apply to any shapes (or even shapes from paths) that I draw immediately afterwards. Is there a setting where I can prevent this continuity of the effects I add? How else do I clear them and restore whatever the default is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you placing each shape on a new layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layer → Layer Style → Clear Layer Style will clear the styles for the current layer. And when you create a new layer, the empty layer style will be inheritted, solving your issue.

If you'd like, Clear Layer Style, Copy Layer Style, and Paste Layer Style can be assigned keyboard shortcuts by visiting Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts.

I have them set to ⌘⇧X, ⌘⇧C, and ⌘⇧V respectively.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know of a way to achieve the clearing of a layer style BEFORE creating a new shape/layer, rather than applying it to said layer after the fact?

Comment: Fill, stroke and layer styles are inherited from the last layer that was selected. So if you'd like to create a shape with no layer styles, select a layer with no layer styles first. :)